# creating table as SYSTEM under another schema make any difference

Tags: oracle11g, schema, create-table

we are using oracle 11g

I am preparing a .sql file of commands to create tables, index, trigger and etc. I have .sql files which should be ran as a particular user.

To avoid above contraint, I am running all DDL as SYSTEM user.

so my question is

will it make any difference to create tables, index and triggers as SYSTEM under another schema lets say abc comapared to creating them as abc itself?

Answer (score 0):

No the operation will be the same but you'll want to ensure that when you create the object you signify which schema to create it under:
`create table OTHER_SCHEMA.TEST_TABLE...`